# ASP.NET OnClientClick="return validate()" not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, validation

In the following aspx page, no matter how I call the OnClientClick="return validate()", the page will post back. The following is what I have tried and the results of each attempt:

OnClientClick="return true" ----- Successful Postback

OnClientClick="return false" ------ No Postback

OnClientClick="return validate()" ----- Successful even with bad input

OnClientClick="return validate()" ------ Successful with good input

OnClientClick="if (!validate()) {return false;}" ----- No Postback regardless of input

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        $('input[type=text]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() === '' || $(this).val() === 'Required Field' || $(this).val() === 'Username' || $(this).val() === 'Password') {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type=text]').focusin(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('Invalid');
            $(this).val('');
        }),
         $('input[type=text]').focusout(function () {

             if ($(this).val() === '') {
                 $(this).removeClass('Valid');
                 $(this).addClass('Invalid');
                 $(this).val('Required Field');
             } else {
                 $(this).addClass('Valid');
             }
         });
    });
</script>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    .Invalid {
        border: 2px solid red;
        background-color: lightpink;
        color: red;
    }

    .Valid {
        border: 2px solid green;
        background-color: lightgreen;
        color: green;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmLogin" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" runat="server" Text="Username"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClientClick="if (!validate()) {return false;}" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the button to:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="return validate();" />
```

If that doesn't work, use the form onsubmit handler, which is probably the better way to go:

```
<form id="frmLogin" runat="server" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

Comment: The flow I am looking for with this button is that it validates client side than if everything is all good, move onto the server side click event.

Comment: @Kurtis Durtis, This will validate on the client side.

Comment: This seems like more of a "work around" than a solution. I want to know why it will only work if I type in return true. Something isn't right, but I cant figure out why.

Comment: @Kurtis Durtis .  OnClientClick is a property of the button just to specify javascript that gets executed when the onclick event is raised.  It is not an event itself, so returning true or false in it will do nothing.  [See the documentation here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx)